# How to change orientation of robot in c#

Tags: c#, oop, error-handling

I have a class called BaseRobot, with the following code

```
{   
//=== Defines the possible orientation of the robot.
//=== Note the order is important to allow cycling to be performed in a meaningful manner.
public enum Compass
{
    North, East, South, West
};

//=== The basic robot.
public class BaseRobot
{
    //--- The behaviour properties that were identified, together with associated state.
    //--- The robot identification number.
   private int mId;
   public int id
   {
       get { return mId; }
   }

   //--- the direction in which the robot is currently facing.
   private Compass mOrientation;
   public Compass Orientation
   {
       get { return mOrientation; }
       set { mOrientation = value; }
   }

   //--- The robot's current position.
   private Point mPosition;
   public Point Position
   {
       get { return mPosition; }
   }


   //--- the robot's home position, where it was originally created.
   public Point mHome;
   public Point Home
   {
       get { return mHome; }
   }

    //--- Turn the orientation left (anti-clockwise) or right (clockwise).
    //--- Implementation relies on the N, E, S, W ordering of the enumeration values to allow the arithmetic to work.

    public void TurnLeft()
    {
        --mOrientation;
        if (mOrientation < 0) mOrientation = Compass.West;
    } // end turnLeft method.    

    public void TurnRight()
    {
        mOrientation = (Compass)(((int)mOrientation + 1) % 4);
    } // end turnRight method.

    //--- Move one unit forward in the current orientation.
    public void Move()
    {
        switch (mOrientation)
        {
            case Compass.North: mPosition.Y++; break;
            case Compass.East: mPosition.X++; break;
            case Compass.South: mPosition.Y--; break;
            case Compass.West: mPosition.X--; break;
        }
    } // end Move method.

    //--- Constructor methods.
    public BaseRobot(int aId)
    {
        mId = aId;
        mHome.X = 0;
        mHome = new Point(0, 0);
        mPosition = mHome;
    }
    public BaseRobot(int aId, int aX, int aY)
    {
        mId = aId;
        mHome = new Point(aX, aY);
        mPosition = mHome;
    } // end BaseRobot constructor methods.



} // end BaseRobot class.

} // end namespace.
```

In my main program class i have this

```
  //calling  BaseRobot constructors 
        var robot1 = new BaseRobot(0);
        var robot2 = new BaseRobot(0,0,0);

        Console.WriteLine("===Defualt Robot===");
        StringBuilder db = new StringBuilder();
        db.AppendFormat("Robot#1 has home at <{0},{0}>. ", robot1.Home.X, robot1.Home.Y);
        db.AppendFormat("It is facing {0} ", robot1.Orientation);
        db.AppendFormat("and is currently at <{0},{0}>.", robot1.Position.X, robot1.Position.Y);
        Console.WriteLine(db.ToString());
```

This works fine but i was wondering how i change the way the robot is facing to south, east and west? Also when i change the home coordinates of the robot to say (35,12), i get the an unhandled error message saying index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less then the size of the argument list.

Comment: Not directly related to your question but I think you have your North and South code round the wrong way. Normally you would see North as moving up the screen in which case it should be `y--` and South moving down so `y++`.

Comment: -1 for code formatting.

Comment: Also, your `db.AppendFormat` are wrong, where you have two items it should be `db.AppendFormat("Robot#1 has home at <{0},{1}>.\r\n", robot1.Home.X, robot1.Home.Y);` so notice `{0}` and `{1}` otherwise you will show same parameter twice. Finally, this code won't run properly as few other issues like base constructor for your robot calls `mHome.X = 0;` before you instantiate `mHome`.

Comment: When you say changing home co-ordinates throws error please show your code demoing this.

Comment: @Belogix db.AppendFormat("Robot#1 has home at <{35},{12}>", robot1.Home.X, robot1.Home.Y);

Answer (score 0):

The TurnLeft and TurnRight methods rotate your robot by modifying the mOrientation field and since your have provided a setter property you can change the direction directly by:

```
robot.Orientation = Compass.West;
```